# Why does uncorrelated random slope and intercept not convergence, but correlated random slope and intercept does converge?

Tags: glmm, glmmtmb

In contrast to what I expected, I am able to fit a model with a correlated random intercept and slope, but not the same model with an uncorrelated random intercept and slope term. I was under the impression that the model with the correlated intercept and slope term should be more complex and hence more difficult to fit, not the other way around. What am I missing? Why does the model with the uncorrelated random effect terms not converge?

I can fit this

```
> w7 <- glmmTMB(weight_t ~ 
+                 tagged + ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292)) + sex_t0 + (age.x | scale_id), 
+               data = long, family = gaussian)
>
```

but I cannot fit this

```
> w6 <- glmmTMB(weight_t ~ 
+                 tagged + ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292)) + sex_t0 + (age.x || scale_id), 
+               data = long, family = gaussian)
Warning message:
In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
>
```

Based on the [glmmTMB trouble shooting page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html), the warning given for the second model suggests that it fails to converge due to being overparameterized is my interpretation. Given that the model with correlated random effect terms converged, it seems unlikely that the second model is not converge due to the random effect variance being estimated to be zero or because of perfect correlation between the random effect terms - indeed, a summary of `w7` shows this.

```
 Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          weight_t ~ tagged + ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292)) +      sex_t0 + (age.x | scale_id)
Data: long

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 17796.4  17856.3  -8886.2  17772.4     1081 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr  
 scale_id (Intercept) 265882.12 515.638        
          age.x           58.02   7.617  -1.00 
 Residual             394590.37 628.164        
Number of obs: 1093, groups:  scale_id, 200

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 3.95e+05 

Conditional model:
                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                105.26      64.70    1.63    0.104    
tagged1                                     39.25      49.64    0.79    0.429    
ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292))1  1428.97     120.68   11.84   <2e-16 ***
ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292))2  3347.65     149.77   22.35   <2e-16 ***
ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292))3  4547.87     175.99   25.84   <2e-16 ***
ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292))4  5986.71     248.17   24.12   <2e-16 ***
ns(age.x, knots = c(73, 134, 220, 292))5  6727.67     201.55   33.38   <2e-16 ***
sex_t0m                                    -46.83      49.91   -0.94    0.348    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```